# Simultaneous equation involving cubics

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have been trying to solve these simultaneous equations but have been unable to find success. I had to resort to using the online graphing tool known as desmos to find out the values of $x$ and $y$. I would really appreciate a step by step guide to solving these equations from anyone who is willing please, as no matter what I use: substitution, elimination or the difference of two squares I am unable to get an answer.

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
(x+y)(x^2-y^2) &= 4 \\
(x-y)(x^2 +y^2) &= \frac{5}{2}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

[Graph of the simultaneous equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJb4L.png)

according to desmos the answers are:
$(x,y)=(-0.5, -1.5)$ or $(1.5,0.5)$

Thank you to anyone who is willing to help with this deceptively simple-looking set of simultaneous equations.

Comment: Add the two equations and simplify first

Comment: Let $y=vx$, then it's easy to eliminate $x$ and get an equation for $v$.

Comment: I think setting $x+y=s$ and $x-y=t$ would also not be a bad idea ...

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Very simple with your hint.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+y)(x^2-y^2) = 4 \tag 1$$
$$(x-y)(x^2 +y^2)= \frac{5}{2}\tag 2$$

As @GerryMyerson suggested in comments, let $y=k x$. Simplify and divide $(1)$ by $(2)$ to obtain
$$\frac{(k+1)^2}{k^2+1}=\frac{8}{5}\quad \implies \quad 3 k^2-10 k+3=0$$ giving as roots $k_1=\frac 13$ and $k_2=3$.

Use  $y=3x$ and replace in $(1)$ to get
$$-32x^3=4 \quad \implies x=-\frac 12 \quad\text{and}\quad y=-\frac 32 $$

Use  $y=\frac x3$ and replace in $(1)$ to get
$$\frac{32 }{27}x^3=4\quad \implies x=\frac 32 \quad\text{and}\quad y=\frac 12 $$

The four complex roots have not been considered.

Comment: In the last sentence, is "roots" a typo for "not"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Thanks for pointing it. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(x+y)(x^2-y^2)=4\\(x-y)(x^2+y^2)=\frac52$$

so $$(x+y)(x+y)(x-y)=4\\2(x-y)(x^2+y^2)=5$$

which is equivalent to $$2(x-y)(x^2+y^2)=(x+y)^2(x-y)+1\Rightarrow\\(x-y)[2(x^2+y^2)-(x+y)^2]=1\Rightarrow\\(x-y)(x^2+y^2-2xy)=1\Rightarrow\\(x-y)(x-y)^2=1\Rightarrow\\(x-y)^3=1$$

If we are confining our solutions to the reals, we have $$x=1+y$$

By substituting in say, the second equation we obtain $$(1+y-y)[(1+y)^2+y^2]=\frac52\Rightarrow\\4y^2+4y-3=0$$

Now, by solving the quadratic, we find the desired pair of solutions $(x,y)=\large(\frac32,\frac12)$ or $(x,y)=\large(-\frac12,-\frac32)$

Comment: This equation has $4$ more complex solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution is brilliant! Out of curiosity, did this come very naturally to you or have you seen something like this before - is there a recognisable pattern to these questions involving squares and whatnot?

Comment: @AlexJones My pleasure, glad to help! Well, there are similarities between the two equations, all involving squares and identities revolving around squares so I tried (it didn't come out of thin air or immediately) to reduce it to something simpler. I guess the.. breakthrough was writing $5$ as $4+1$. If you like, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=x+y, v=x-y$, then $u^2v=4, v(u^2+v^2)/2=\frac52 \implies u^2v+v^3=5\implies v^3=1$.

If one is looking only for real solutions, $v=1, u=\pm2$, gives $(x, y)\in \{(\frac32, -\frac12), (-\frac12, \frac32)\}$.

For the complex ones, use $v=\omega, \omega^2$ where $\omega$ is a non-real cube root of unity.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Making $x = \frac 12(u+v),\ \ y = \frac 12(u-v)$ we have

$$
\cases{
u^2 v = 4\\
u^2 v +v^3= 5
}\Rightarrow v^3=1,\ \ u = \frac 12,\ \ \text{etc.}
$$

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the substitution idea, how did you come up with the exact expressions for the substitutions?

Comment: When we have products involving $x+y$ and $x-y$ is a typical way to try simplifications.

Comment: is comes from $x+y = u$ and $x-y=v$ and represents a plane rotation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$.